# rolling sum of different length over vector

Tags: r

say I have a vector:

```
vec = 1:10
vec
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

and for different integers `k` I want the sums of k successive elements of my vector, i.e. my desired output for k=1 is the vector itself

```
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

and for k=2:

```
[1]  3  5  7  9  11  13  15  17  19
```

and so on - in this example k = 10 is the last possible where I want:

```
[1] 55
```

i.e. the sum over all 10 entries of my vector.

In my real data `vec` is of length ~10^6, `k=1:1000` and the entries are signed real numbers.

EDIT: 
I was curious about performance so I did my first benchmark:

```
> library(RcppRoll)
> library(zoo)
> library(microbenchmark)
> 
> f <- Vectorize(function(x, k)RcppRoll::roll_sum(x, k),  vectorize.args = "k")
> out = list()
> vec = na.omit(myrealdata)
> vec = vec[1:1e4]
> mb = microbenchmark(Khashaa = f(vec, 1:100), 
+                     mra68 = for(k in (1:100)){out[[k]] <- k*rollmean(vec, k)}, 
+                     akrun = sapply(1:100, function(x) rollsum(vec, k=x)), times = 100)
> print(mb)
Unit: milliseconds
    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval
 Khashaa  48.12953  49.08398  49.89553  49.55445  50.27705   53.23208   100
   mra68 557.93112 564.74246 578.07404 568.95936 576.81239  858.52096   100
   akrun 549.48471 556.68814 570.50853 560.17078 565.31508 1190.12545   100
```

I tested on part of my real data and for a smaller `k` (for larger `k` all algos slow down due to RAM issues). Khashaa's algo is the clear winner and has the added bonus of being able to handle NAs. However along the answers suggested by akrun and mra68 this could be done with `rollapply(... mean(..., na.rm=T))`. Thanks for the great answers!

Comment: For k=2, it would be `3 5 7 9...` Try `library(zoo);sapply(1:10, function(x) rollsum(vec, k=x))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
x <- 1:10
k <- 1:10
f <- Vectorize(function(x, k)RcppRoll::roll_sum(x, k),  vectorize.args = "k")
f(x, k)


[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[2]]
[1]  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19

[[3]]
[1]  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27

[[4]]
[1] 10 14 18 22 26 30 34

[[5]]
[1] 15 20 25 30 35 40

[[6]]
[1] 21 27 33 39 45

[[7]]
[1] 28 35 42 49

[[8]]
[1] 36 44 52

[[9]]
[1] 45 54

[[10]]
[1] 55
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for pointing out this package and just for completeness: `library(RcppRoll)`

Answer (score 2):

Since the mean and the sum are strongly related we can also use the 'rollmean' function from the 'zoo' package:

```
vec <- 1:10
for ( k in (1:10) ) { print(k*rollmean(vec,k)) }
```

The output is, as desired:

```
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
[1]  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19
[1]  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27
[1] 10 14 18 22 26 30 34
[1] 15 20 25 30 35 40
[1] 21 27 33 39 45
[1] 28 35 42 49
[1] 36 44 52
[1] 45 54
[1] 55
```

This is perhaps more elementary than the 'RcppRoll'-solution.
I also checked the speed using a vector of size 10^6:

```
> vec <- sample(1000000) / 1000000
> k <- 1000
> system.time(for (i in (1:100)){ k*rollmean(vec,k)})/100
       User      System verstrichen 
     1.2972      0.0000      1.3075
```